# laravel return false for correct credentials on attemptLogin

Tags: php, laravel

in `laravel "^7.11.0"` i dont any problem with our custom login and when i update that to new version this code return false:

```
//LoginController.php
$this->attemptLogin($request)

//trait AuthenticatesUsers.php
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

but in `7.11.0` return `true`, i don't know what happen on new version of `laravel "^7.28.3"` which that return false, and that cause i can't update `laravel`:

my custom login:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Events\UserAuthenticate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if (auth()->validate($request->only('username','password'))) {
            $user = User::whereUsername($request->username)->first();

            if ($user->lock) {
                $request->session()->flash('error',__('message.your_account_locked'));
                return view('layouts.backend.pages.auth.account.locked_account');
            }elseif (!$user->active) {
                $checkActivationCode = $user->activationCode()->where('expire', '>=', Carbon::now())->latest()->first();

                if ($checkActivationCode != null) {
                    if ($checkActivationCode->expire > Carbon::now()) {
                        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

                        $request->session()->flash('error',__('message.please_active_your_account'));
                        return view('layouts.backend.pages.auth.account.active_account');
                    }
                }else{
                    return redirect()->to('/page/userAccountActivation/create');
                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            dd('aaaaaa');
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'g-recaptcha-response', 'recaptcha'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: upgrade to what new version?

Comment: @lagbox to `"^7.28.3"` version

Comment: please provide all of this controller

Comment: @lagbox i pasted full code on this controller

Comment: then as stated in the answer you need to add the `username` method if you wish to use `attemptLogin` otherwise it will use the 'email' field from the Request and in the query for the user.

Comment: also the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait does not exist in `laravel/framework` it comes from `laravel/ui` and `AuthenticatesUsers@username` has always returned `'email'`

Answer (score 1):

The default fields that are used for the credentials are `email` and `password`
You should define a `username` method on the `LoginController` so the `credentials` method will pull the correct credentials when `attemptLogin` calls it to use a different field from `email` for the username field in the credentials:

> "By default, Laravel uses the `email` field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a `username` method on your `LoginController`:" - [Laravel 7.x Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating)

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

As a side note, with what you are doing after `auth()->validate(...)` you have the user already from the auth system, you can log them in yourself from there:

```
if ($this->guard()->validate(....)) {
    $user = $this->guard()->user();

    ...

    $this->guard()->login($user, $remember);

    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Unless you are listening for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting` event or the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed` event you don't need to call `attemptLogin` at this point, you have already done the job of the guards `attempt` method (minus those 2 events).

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Authentication - Authenticating - Username Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating)

Comment: by default i changed `email` to `username` and laravel doesn't change this file after upgrading or updating to new version

Comment: right but you were not showing that method (there is no method in the your code you have above [without it your controller code is not correct]) so there was no way to know that and you are directly passing the values you want to `$request->only` instead of using `$this->credentials()` and you have the field hardcoded on the direct query you are doing with the user model

Comment: i'm not sure what happened, after multiple upgrade and downgrade laravel version, my problem solved